# Having trouble setting position of UISlider in spritekit for all devices?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

Im using this code to set the position correctly for all my devices. The problem Im having is if I set the position of the slider in the 4s the iphone 6+ position changes. Same goes for my other devices. How do I get every device to perfectly position the sliders? Im in spritekit btw.

```
//iphone4s
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.maxLength < 568.0 {
    middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(180, 50, 150, 20))
    middleSlider.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    middleSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb2"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view?.addSubview(middleSlider)
    bottomAudioControlBg.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 7)

}



//iphone5
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.maxLength == 568.0 {

}



//iphone6
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.maxLength == 667.0 {

}



//iphone6+
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.maxLength == 736.0 {
    middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(255, 50, 150, 20))
    middleSlider.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    middleSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb2"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view?.addSubview(middleSlider)


}




//ipad
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.maxLength == 1024.0 {

}



//ipadpro
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.maxLength == 1366.0 {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way to much code for such a problem:)

Using a simple scaling-factor you can easily solve this:

```
 let scaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 320

        let middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(180 * scaleFactor, 50, 150, 20))
        middleSlider.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb2"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.view?.addSubview(middleSlider)
```

Comment: I have one question will this work for the ipad also?

Comment: I tried it for the ipad and the sliders are not in the right position like in the iphone.

Comment: that's probably because ipad has an other format. You could first check whether the device is an ipad or iphone and then asign `scaleFactor` correctly

Comment: what should the scalefactor for the ipad be?

Comment: I think `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 768`, but I haven't tested it